# PHP 7.2+ Mcrypt functions throw "Deprecated Error" even if Mcrypt extension module is installed

Tags: deprecated, mcrypt, pecl, php-7.2, error-reporting

**[Mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)** functions have been deprecated since PHP 7.1.0 and removed since PHP 7.2.0

I need to move to PHP 7.3.9 some code that relies upon Mcrypt, so I installed **Mcrypt extension** via PECL.

The problem is that if **error reporting** bit `E_DEPRECATED` is set (either via **php.ini** configuration file or with `error_reporting()` function during runtime) Mcrypt functions stop execution with **mcrypt_... function is deprecated** error.

Is there a way to leave `E_DEPRECATED` set but allow execution of Mcrypt functions as Mcrypt extension is loaded?

Comment: This is your error handler. It's not the default behaviour. Find your error handler and allow an exception for deprecated cases such as this one.  By your error handler I mean your application is over riding the default error handler

Comment: You wouldn't be having issues such as this if you had installed https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat . At that point mcrypt would have been emulated with either OpenSSL or a pure-PHP implementation, if OpenSSL wasn't available

Comment: Did you find a way to allow execution of mcrypt functions Paolo?

Comment: @Shaun the only way is not setting the E_DEPRECATED bit